# Change sentence in words

Tags: java, string

I am a beginner in programming. I have a question about coding which is below.

```
String str = "Hello java";
String words[]=str.split(" ");
    for(String finalStr:words){
        System.out.println(finalStr);
}
```

I know the answer will be print each word. But I don't understand the line which is "for(String finalStr:words)" can someone explain about how its work ?

Comment: Can you do some google about enhanced for loop in java?

Comment: it means for each string in words we name them as finalStr and process them in this block

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-string-array-reference-java-5-for-loop-syntax